# I do not understand how screen.fill() works

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

The screenfill is supposed to change the background colour. But if I draw anything before screenfill, it is not showing up but if I draw something after it, then it works fine with the updated background colour. 
The 2 codes I am talking about:
In the loop (i is initialized to 0 before loop):

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255-i, i, 0),`pygame.Rect(30,30,60,60)`
i=(i+1)%255
screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
```

This code shows black screen

```
screen.fill((0,0,0))
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255-i, i, 0), `pygame.Rect(30,30,60,60)`
i=(i+1)%255
```

This is working fine. Why is it happening?

Comment: Are you asking why, when you fill the screen, you can't see whatever was there before?

Comment: Pygame has no concept of background or foreground. `screen.fill` simple fills the whole screen with one colour.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman The rectangle is being drawn in the first, then the screen is being filled up. We should be able to see the rectangle for a brief moment before it turns black for a brief moment , then again the rectangle and so on. But all I get is a black screen. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a `pygame.display.update()` call at some point in your code, ideally it should be the last line of the main loop. May be somewhere else, but should be after your snippets. That is the command which actually draws on the screen of your pc.

Functions like those of the `pygame.draw` module or `pygame.fill` draw on an internal surface (an object stored in the memory of your pc). You can imagine they simply edit a 2D array, where each element of this array is a 3 or 4 long tuple storing the RGB or RGBA color of the pixel.
Nothing is actually shown on the screen until you call `pygame.display.update()`. Basically `pygame.display.update()` reads that 2D array and changes the pixels of your screen accordingly to the values in the 2D array *at the moment* when `pygame.display.update()` is called.

This means that in the following snippet:

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255-i, i, 0),`pygame.Rect(30,30,60,60)`
i=(i+1)%255
screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
```

You first draw the rectangle, then fill the whole screen with black, then show the final result (a black screen) on the pc screen when the code calls `pygame.display.update()`. No chance to see the rectangle.

Instead

```
screen.fill((0,0,0))
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255-i, i, 0), `pygame.Rect(30,30,60,60)`
i=(i+1)%255
```

here you first fill the screen with black, then draw the rectangle, then show the final result, which is a black background with a colored rectangle.